¿Cómo hacer que se muestren dígitos simultáneamente en un display de 7 segmentos cuádruple en arduino?
A partir de un sensor dht, estoy leyendo la temperatura ambiente y mi objetivo es que se muestre la temperatura en un display de 7 segmentos cúadruple, finalizando con la C de grados celsius.
Recibo la temperatura desde el sensor, convierto la cantidad en un arreglo, por ejemplo si son 19 grados sería [1,9], y cada número lo llevo al display correspondiente, en el ejemplo el 1 sería en el display 2 y el 9 el 3.
Necesito que todos los dígitos se muestren a la vez, con lo que tengo sólo se muestran uno a uno en el display que corresponde.
Los números están representados de esta manera
void ocho() {
    digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

Y este es el código
void loop() {
    // Mostrar los dígitos en los displays de 7 segmentos
    for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; ++i) {
        switch (digits[i]) {
            case 0:
                c();
                break;
            case 1:
                uno();
                break;
            case 2:
                dos();
                break;
            case 3:
                tres();
                break;
            case 4:
                cuatro();
                break;
            case 5:
                cinco();
                break;
            case 6:
                seis();
                break;
            case 7:
                siete();
                break;
            case 8:
                ocho();
                break;
            case 9:
                nueve();
                break;
        }

        // Mostrar el dígito actual en el display correspondiente
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                prender2();
                break;
            case 1:
                prender3();
                break;
        }

        // Esperar un breve momento antes de cambiar al siguiente dígito
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println(roundedTemperature);
    }

    // Mostrar la letra 'C' en el cuarto display
    c();
    prender4();
    delay(1000);
}

Y cada display lo enciendo de esta manera, por ejemplo este es para prender el segundo:
void prender2() {
  digitalWrite(digito1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digito2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(digito3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digito4, HIGH);
}



Me da la impresión de que tienes conectados los segmentos en paralelo, es decir, que cuando activas el pin A, das corriente al segmento A en los cuatro dígitos simultáneamente, y luego con el pin "digitoN" decides cual de los cuatro dígitos finalmente se ilumina.
Para colocar y visualizar valores distintos en cada dígito, tendrías que prender y apagar cada dígito en rápida sucesión, para conseguir el efecto de "persistencia de la visión".
La solución es eliminar todos los delay() y Serial.println(), algo como
void loop() {
    // Mostrar los dígitos en los displays de 7 segmentos
    for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; ++i) {
        switch (digits[i]) {
            case 0:
                c();
                break;
   ...
            case 9:
                nueve();
                break;
        }

        // Mostrar el dígito actual en el display correspondiente
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                prender2();
                break;
            case 1:
                prender3();
                break;
        }

        // Mostrar la letra 'C' en el cuarto display
        c();
        prender4();
}

Si lo haces rápidamente, todos los dígitos se verán iluminados al mismo tiempo.
Si necesitas también mostrar la temperatura por la serial, no lo puedes hacer dentro del for. Hazlo a continuación del for, pero no en cada pasada por loop(). Espera unos 10 segundos entre cada println(). Usa millis() para contar el tiempo transcurrido.
void loop() {

  static unsigned int oldDisplay = 0;
  unsigned int now = millis();

    // Mostrar los dígitos en los displays de 7 segmentos
  for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; ++i) {
    ... 
  } /* fin del for */

  /* 10.000 ms nos da un intervalo de 10 segundos
     entre cada Serial.println() */  
  if (now - oldDisplay >= 10000L) {
      Serial.println(roundedTemperature);
      oldDisplay = now;
      }
} /* Fin del loop */

Alternativas
Otra alternativa es usar cuatro shift register-serial a paralelo en serie, como el 74hc595. Bastaría con alimentar el shift register una vez, y estos mantendrían los segmentos iluminados simúltaneamente hasta que decidas cambiar los valores.
O, más simple aún, puedes usar un módulo con interfaz I2C. Mira https://www.makerguides.com/tm1637-arduino-tutorial/

Hace poco tuve que usar uno de esos. En mí caso, decidí utilizar el Timer1 para que muestre un dígito diferente cada vez. A una frecuencia elevada el cambio no se nota.
char digitos[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    static int vez = 0;
    vez = (vez + 1) % 4;
    
    int digito = vez + 1;
    desactivarTodos();
    bcd(digitos[vez]);
    activarDigito(digito);
}

Como puedes ver lo importante es desactivar los 4 display primero, cambiar el dígito en cuestión y finalmente activar solo el dígito que deseas mostrar.
Cabe mencionar que utilicé un conversor de BCD a 7 segmentos y 3 transistores NPN y uno PNP. Sin embargo la idea es la misma.
Por eso la función activarDigito luce así (y desactivarDigito es exactamente al revés):
void activarDigito(int n){
    switch (n){
        case 1:
            digitalWrite(PIN_D1, true);
            break;
        case 2:
            digitalWrite(PIN_D2, true);
            break;
        case 3:
            digitalWrite(PIN_D3, true);
            break;
        case 4:
            digitalWrite(PIN_D4, false);
            break;
    }
}

La configuración del Timer1 es la siguiente:
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12); // Modo CTC
OCR1A = 80; // Unos 192 Hz 
TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // Habilita la interrupción de comparación A
TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10); // Inicia el timer con prescaler de 1024

